# How to solve the line search error in a minimization problem using 'fminunc' in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find the  B  (2*2 matrix) that makes the elements of  beta_d (1*4 vector) which is a function of B  matrix, equal to the corresponding ones of a "given" beta_u (1*4 vector), i.e.  beta_d(1,1) = beta_u(1,1) && beta_d(1,2) = beta_u(1,2) && beta_d(1,3) = beta_u(1,3) && beta_d(1,4) = beta_u(1,4).
So, I started using 'fminunc' to find the value of B (2*2 matrix) that minimizes the difference between the corresponding elements in the two vectors. However, it usually gives me the following error:

```
Error using lineSearch
Search direction is not a descent direction; roundoff errors may be affecting convergence.
Error in fminusub (line 186)
          lineSearch(funfcn,x,dir,f,dirDerivative, ...
Error in fminunc (line 472)
   [x,FVAL,GRAD,HESSIAN,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT] = fminusub(funfcn,x, ...
```

Can anyone help me solving this 'fminuc' problem? or suggest another way to find the value of B (2*2 matrix) that minimizes the difference between the corresponding elements in the two vectors beta_u and beta_d?
My code is:

```
clc;
clear;
% System paramters:
c_l = 4;
counter = 0;
H = [0.7182   -1.9924; 0.8306    0.0195; -0.6868   -0.7119; -0.1692    0.1084];
A = [-3 1; 1 0];
C = [1  -2; 0  1; 1 -2; 0 1]; 
P_u = 25*eye(4);
P_d = 25*eye(2);
beta_u = [50.4551   59.1605   50.4551   59.1605];
beta_d = zeros(1,4); % intial value
%store inputs to a struct for shorter syntax
s=struct;
[s.H,s.A,s.C,s.P_u,s.P_d,s.C_l]=deal(H,A,C,P_u,P_d,c_l);
while (sum(abs(beta_u-beta_d))>0.1 && counter< 500)
    initial_guess = randn(2,2);
    OLS = @(B_d,input_vars)sum(abs(beta_u-myfun(B_d,input_vars)).^2);%ordinary least squares cost function
    opts = optimoptions(@fminunc,'MaxIterations',10000,'MaxFunctionEvaluations',50000);
    [B,FVAL,grad] = fminunc(OLS, initial_guess, opts,s);
    input_vars = s;
    [beta_d,D_d]= myfun(B,input_vars);
    counter = counter+1;
end
%calculate beta_d from B and the other inputs
function [beta_d,D_d]=myfun(B,input_vars)
%load parameters
s=input_vars;[H,A,C,P_u,P_d,C_l]=deal(s.H,s.A,s.C,s.P_u,s.P_d,s.C_l);
for j=1:1:2
    d(j) = (B(j,:)*P_d*B(j,:)')/((2^(2*C_l))-(norm(A(:,j))^2));
end
D_d = diag(d);
for i=1:1:4   
    V_d(i)=C(i,:)*P_d*B'*H(i,:)'*inv(1+H(i,:)*(A'*D_d*A+B*P_d*B')*H(i,:)');
    sigma_d(i)=norm((V_d(i)*H(i,:)*B-C(i,:))*(P_d^(1/2)))^2+(V_d(i)^2)*(1+H(i,:)*A'*D_d*A*H(i,:)');
    beta_d(i)=((P_u(i,i))/sigma_d(:,i));   
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `'Display','Iter'` to your `optimoptions` call, so that you can see more details of what the optimizer is doing. It's possible that the optimizer has gotten into a poorly conditioned region, or is close to a local minimum or a saddle point, causing the finite difference approximation of the gradient of your cost function to behave poorly.

One suggestion is to try setting [`FiniteDifferenceStepSize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html) to some small value in the `optimoptions` call.

Here's an example:

```
optimoptions(@fminunc, 'MaxIterations', 10000, 'MaxFunctionEvaluations', 50000, 'Display', 'Iter', 'FiniteDifferenceStepSize', 1e-3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, why doesn't fminunc find the minimum B matrix that makes beta_d vector equal the corresponding ones in beta_u vector? is there any problem in my code?